TypeScript: group items according to shared attributes and assign them a groupID
I want to implement a function that does the following:

Takes an array of products as an argument
returns a new array of products, each of which has a new groupId attribute.
Different products will share the same groupId if they share the same common attributes, the attributes being determined by groupIfIdentical

See function skeleton here:
    function groupProductsBySharedAttributes(
      products: Product[],
      groupIfIdentical: (keyof Product)[],
      initialGroupId: string,
    ) {
      
    }

Products containing identical attributes should be grouped like this:
export function productsAreIdentical(
  prod1: Product,
  prod2: Product,
  groupIfIdentical: (keyof Product)[],
) {
  for (const key of groupIfIdentical) {
    if (prod1[key] !== prod2[key]) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}

Example:
const prods = [{
  country: 'china',
  material: 'steel',
  sku: 1453
},
{
  country: 'china',
  material: 'steel',
  sku: 4874
},
{
  country: 'japan',
  material: 'steel',
  sku: 4874
},
]


const result = groupProductsBySharedAttributes(prods, ['country', 'material'], 1001)

result = [
  {
  country: 'china',
  material: 'steel',
  sku: 1453,
  groupId: 1001
},
{
  country: 'china',
  material: 'steel',
  sku: 4874,
  groupId: 1001
},
{
  country: 'japan',
  material: 'steel',
  sku: 4874,
  groupId: 1002
}
]


In the groupProductsBySharedAttributes function
First you will initialize a Map object called groupIdMap where you will store the Stringify version of the object of the groupIfIdentical keys of the product as a key and groupId as a value, also you will initialize a new array called groupedProducts of the products but after inserting the groupId, then you will loop through the products array check if the key exist in the groupIdMap , if yes, they are identical, if not save the new key and groupId ( after increment by one ), and in both cases push in the groupedProducts
interface Product {
    [key: string]: any;
}

function productsAreIdentical(
    prod1: Product,
    prod2: Product,
    groupIfIdentical: (keyof Product)[]
): boolean {
    for (const key of groupIfIdentical) {
        if (prod1[key] !== prod2[key]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function groupProductsBySharedAttributes(
    products: Product[],
    groupIfIdentical: (keyof Product)[],
    initialGroupId: string,
): Product[] {
    let groupId = parseInt(initialGroupId); // Convert initialGroupId to an integer for easy incrementation
    const groupedProducts: Product[] = [];
    const groupIdMap = new Map<string, number>(); // Maps a stringified key to a groupId

    products.forEach(product => {
        let foundGroup = false;
        for (const [key, id] of groupIdMap) {
            const keyAttributes = JSON.parse(key);
            if (productsAreIdentical(product, keyAttributes, groupIfIdentical)) {
                product.groupId = id;
                foundGroup = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!foundGroup) {
            const key = JSON.stringify(
                groupIfIdentical.reduce((acc, attr) => {
                    acc[attr] = product[attr];
                    return acc;
                }, {} as Partial<Product>)
            );

            if (!groupIdMap.has(key)) {
                groupIdMap.set(key, groupId);
                product.groupId = groupId;
                groupId++;
            }
        }

        groupedProducts.push(product);
    });

    return groupedProducts;
}

// Example usage
const prods = [
    { country: 'china', material: 'steel', sku: 1453 },
    { country: 'china', material: 'steel', sku: 4874 },
    { country: 'japan', material: 'steel', sku: 4874 }
];

const result = groupProductsBySharedAttributes(prods, ['country', 'material'], '1001');
console.log(result);

PLAYGROUND
